# Uncaught ReferenceError while trying to implement addEventListener on a webView Button in android studio

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin, webview

I'm writing **Js code** that I'm injecting into an Android Webview to search for particular URLs and set a button on them, for which I have an EventListener. When I click it, it works; it outputs the logs button and even changes colour, but the interface never gets activated, it says: `ReferenceError Uncaught`.
To be more precise **error : [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: downloadListener is not defined"**

###### Here is my code:

```
   private void setup(WebView webView, String videoUrl) {

       webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
       // Define a Java object to be exposed to JavaScript
       class DownloadListener {
           @JavascriptInterface
           public void onDownloadButtonClick(String buttonId, String videoSrc) {
               Log.d("DownloadListener", "Button with id " + buttonId + " was clicked for video with src " + videoSrc);
               // Handle the button click in Java code here
           }
       }

       // Add the Java object to the JavaScript environment
       String jsCode = "function addDownloadOverlayToVideo(videoSrc) { " +
               "  var video = document.querySelector('video[src=\"' + videoSrc + '\"]'); " +
               "  var parent = video.parentNode; " +
               "  parent.style.width = '100%'; " +
               "  var overlay = parent.querySelector('.download-overlay'); " +
               "  if (!overlay) { " +
               "    overlay = document.createElement('div'); " +
               "    overlay.className = 'download-overlay'; " +
               "    overlay.style.position = 'absolute'; " +
               "    overlay.style.display = 'inline-block'; " +
               "    overlay.style.top = '5px'; " +
               "    overlay.style.right = '5px'; " +
               "    overlay.style.margin = '5px'; " +
               "    overlay.style.zIndex = '9999'; " +
               "    var button = document.createElement('button'); " +
               "    button.innerHTML = 'Download'; " +
               "    var id = 'download-button'; " +
               "    button.id = id; " +
               "    button.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000'; " +
               "    button.style.padding = '10px 20px'; " +
               "    button.style.borderRadius = '5px'; " +
               "    button.style.color = '#FFFFFF'; " +
               "    button.style.fontSize = '18px'; " +
               "    button.addEventListener('mousedown', function() { " +
               "      this.style.transform = 'translateY(2px)'; " +
               "      this.style.backgroundColor = '#000000'; " +
               "      downloadListener.onDownloadButtonClick(this.id, video.src); " +
               "    }); " +
               "    overlay.appendChild(button); " +
               "    parent.style.position = 'relative'; " +
               "    parent.appendChild(overlay); " +
               "  } " +
               "} " +
               "addDownloadOverlayToVideo('" + videoUrl + "');";

       // Run the JavaScript code on the UI thread


       webView.addJavascriptInterface(new DownloadListener(), "downloadListener");
       webView.post(() -> webView.evaluateJavascript(jsCode, null));
   }
`

Note I am trying to add a button onto Videos programmatically on specific videos and want to listen to what link based button is clicked but the interface is not working
```

Comment: You need to add the full error message if you want help diagnosing errors

Comment: error : [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: downloadListener is not defined"